# How can I select the default VLC Sound device?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Without changing the default audio device for the system, is there anyway on the command line to specify the default sound output device using vlc? Can you specify a different sound output device and a different sound input device on the command line?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using pulseaudio, as in Ubuntu. Simply set `PULSE_SINK` on the command line.

```
PULSE_SINK=1 vlc
```

You can find out the value use by inspecting the Pulse Audio syncs with `pacmd list-sinks`.